# When someone says "something appears to be broken", is he certain or is he assuming?

Tags: verbs

When someone says *"something appears to be broken"*, does that mean he is assuming that it might be broken or is he certain that the said thing is broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***appears to be*** and ***seems to be*** both carry the same meaning - that something gives the impression of being a certain way. It's not a simple assumption - it implies a high level of probability, while still allowing for a margin of error.

In practice, ***appears to be*** and ***seems to be*** are both used to state something as fact, while providing a sense of distance or insulation from having to stand by that fact.

> The child **seems to be** healthy, but the doctor is concerned.
>
> The house **appears to be** in good condition.

Both can also be used to convey an element of surprise, while still stating something as fact.

> There **appears to be** an error with my bill!

Comment: It "appears"  can also be used as an understatement, when something is obviously broken. Context is king.